# ¿Cómo hacer la internacionalización de una aplicación web?

Tags: html, html5, internacionalización

Tengo una aplicación web pequeña (una sola página con 4-5 vistas que luego paso a Android/iPhone con Cordova) que tiene texto en varios idiomas. En el pasado había controlado la internacionalización con CSS, pero cuando el número de frases creció (hasta unas 60), me pasé a una manera muy básica con JavaScript puro, sin plugins de ningún tipo.

El método es sencillo: tengo las diferentes cadenas en JSON, y la clave para cada cadena coincide con la un data-atributo del elemento que cambiará (marcado con una clase específica), entonces selecciono esos elementos y cambio su contenido. Algo como esto (simplificado):

```js
// JSON con las cadenas traducidas a los diferentes idiomas
frases = {
  "en": {
    "idioma": "Change language:",
    "lan-en": "English",
    "lan-es": "Spanish"
  },
  "es": {
    "idioma": "Cambiar idioma:",
    "lan-en": "Inglés",
    "lan-es": "Español"
  }
}

// función que cambia todos los elementos al nuevo idioma
function cambiarIdioma(lang) {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".intfrase");
  for (var x = 0; x < elems.length; x++)
    elems[x].innerHTML = frases[lang][ elems[x].dataset.id ];
}

// cargar el idioma por defecto
cambiarIdioma("es");
```

```html
<div>
  <span data-id="idioma" class="intfrase"></span>
  <button onclick="cambiarIdioma('es')" data-id="lan-es" class="intfrase"></button>
  <button onclick="cambiarIdioma('en')" data-id="lan-en" class="intfrase"></button>
</div>
```

Ahora estoy ampliando y reescribiendo parte de la aplicación para mejorarla, y uno de los puntos que creo podrían ser mejorados es cómo se realiza la internacionalización, especialmente teniendo en cuenta que el número de frases se va a duplicar.

¿Cómo se puede mejorar lo que ya tengo? ¿Qué otros métodos hay para conseguir la internacionalización de una aplicación web? ¿Qué ventajas tienen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me parece una buena idea la que planteas en tu código, la única desventaja que veo, es que se requiere estar creando identificadores para los textos (mucha imaginación o un estándar para no caer en info desordenada), como Joomla (TEXT_HELLO, TEXT_THANKS).

Otra opción a sugerir es algo parecido a lo tuyo, pero cambia un poco la forma de operar:

```js
/**
 * JSON con las cadenas traducidas a los diferentes idiomas.
 * No hay español, por ser el default.
 */
frases = {
  "en": {
    "Cambiar idioma:": "Change language:",
    "Español": "Spanish",
    "Inglés": "English",
    "Portugués": "Portuguese"
  },
  "pt": {
    "Cambiar idioma:": "Mudar idioma:",
    "Español": "Espanhol",
    "Inglés": "Inglês",
    "Portugués": "Português"
  }
};

/**
 * Función que cambia todos los elementos al nuevo idioma.
 *
 * @param {string} lang
 */
function cambiarIdioma(lang) {
  // Habilita las 2 siguientes para guardar la preferencia.
  // lang = lang || sessionStorage.getItem('app-lang') || 'es';
  // sessionStorage.setItem('app-lang', lang);

  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tr]');
  for (var x = 0; x < elems.length; x++) {
    elems[x].innerHTML = frases.hasOwnProperty(lang)
      ? frases[lang][elems[x].dataset.tr]
      : elems[x].dataset.tr;
  }
}

window.onload = function(){
  cambiarIdioma();
  
  document
    .getElementById('btn-es')
    .addEventListener('click', cambiarIdioma.bind(null, 'es'));

  document
    .getElementById('btn-en')
    .addEventListener('click', cambiarIdioma.bind(null, 'en'));

  document
    .getElementById('btn-pt')
    .addEventListener('click', cambiarIdioma.bind(null, 'pt'));
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span data-tr="Cambiar idioma:"></span>
  <button data-tr="Español" id="btn-es"></button>
  <button data-tr="Inglés" id="btn-en"></button>
  <button data-tr="Portugués" id="btn-pt"></button>
</div>
```

Me baso en como Magento y Yii (entre otros frameworks) lo hacen.

Comment: No entiendo bien cuando dices que Joomla y Magento usan métodos distintos, la verdad yo veo que ambos tienen un nombre de string y un valor para cada idioma. La diferencia que yo veo es que Magento1 tiene varios métodos de traducción según como el contexto (csv, js, inline, db).