# Pagina multilenguaje con jquery y javaScript funcional para IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

Necesito hacer mi html multilenguaje, he visto en Internet que se puede hacer con php pero que hay gente que tambien lo ha hecho con jQuery y con javascript. Se que en principio la parte de cargar el idioma lo tendria que hacer desde servidor pero quiero hacerlo con jQuery.

Hasta ahora probando he conseguido hacer este pequeño ejemplo

```
<select id="idioma" onchange="cambiaId()">
  <option value="es">Español</option>
  <option value="en">Ingles</option>
</select>
<script>
  var _lang = $("#idioma").val();

  var aa = {
    en: "Hello",
    es: "Hola"
  };
function cambiaId(){
    _lang = $("#idioma").val();
    alert(_lang)
}
</script>
<div id="a">
  <script>
    document.write(aa[_lang])
  </script>
</div>
```

Este funciona correctamente cuando se carga el html coge el idioma selecionado y escribe. El problema es cuando cambio de idioma que actualizo la variable lang, pero no se como actualizar en la pagina para que cambie los valores.

En el ejemplo solo se ve una variable y ponerla dentro de la funcion y actualizarla es facil. El problema viene cuando tienes que actualizar 200 variables. Lo que necesito es actualizar de alguna manera el texto que escribo con las variables.

Creo que la manera mas correcta de hacerlo seria que al cambiar el valor del select se guarde en una cockie el nuevo valor y que al recargar la pagina, deje como selected el valor pasado por la cockie

### EDICION

Despues de mostrarme la respuesta a mi problema en esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22339/c%C3%B3mo-hacer-la-internacionalizaci%C3%B3n-de-una-aplicaci%C3%B3n-web) de implantarla en mi html, necesito hacerla funcional para IE9.

He creado un nuevo js que se llama *multilenguaje.js* y lleva el siguiente codigo:

```
frases = {
    "es": {//Literales en castellano},
    "en": {//Literales en ingles}
/**
 * Función que cambia todos los elementos al nuevo idioma.
 *
 * @param {string} lang
 */
function cambiarIdioma() {
  lang = $("#idioma").val();
  // Habilita las 2 siguientes para guardar la preferencia.
  // lang = lang || sessionStorage.getItem('app-lang') || 'es';
  // sessionStorage.setItem('app-lang', lang);

  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tr]');
  for (var x = 0; x < elems.length; x++) {
    elems[x].innerHTML = frases.hasOwnProperty(lang)
      ? frases[lang][elems[x].dataset.tr]
      : elems[x].dataset.tr;
  }
}
```

Para selecionar el idioma lo hago asi:

```
<div>
        <span data-tr="cambiaIdioma"></span>
        <select id="idioma" onchange="cambiarIdioma()">
            <option data-tr="idioma-es" value="es"></option>
            <option data-tr="idioma-en" value="en"></option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Esta solucion me funciona en Google Chrome y Firefox pero cuando lo hago en IE me da el siguiente error.

> No se puede obtener la propiedad 'tr' de referencia nula o sin definir

Y me señala a esta linea del script:

`frases[lang][elems[x].dataset.tr]`

Comment: actualizar la pagina con `location.reload` no te sirve?

Comment: @lois6b esto recarga la pagina y me vuelve a poner el español por defecto

Comment: @lois6b a lo mejor guardando el dato en una cockie y recagando la pagina funcionaria pero eso no se como hacerlo.

Comment: @mariano tambien lo pensé pero igual vale solo para este caso que solo es un texto. No se, como pedia actualizar la pagina ..

Comment: @Mariano evidentemente eso funcionaria, pero no es lo que pretendo, en el ejemplo solo se ve una varible y ponerla dentro de la funcion es facil. El problema viene cuando tienes que actualizar 200 varibles. Lo que necesito es actualizar de alguna manera el texto que escribo con las varibles

Comment: Mira [esta pregunta que hice](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/22339/250) hace un tiempo. Creo que lo que buscas es el mismo código de la pregunta o el de la respuesta aceptada.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro si, es exactamente lo mismo que buscaba, muchas gracias

Comment: @Mariano supongo que se podria decir que es duplicado aunque desconocia esa pregunta, de todas formas quiero aplicar ciertos cambios a la respuesta de esa pregunta y cambiar varias cosas por lo que si me da un error o algo editare la pregunta o hare una nueva en funcion de si esta se cierra o no

Comment: @Mariano como dije, seguro que tendria algun problema mas...

Answer (score -1):

Ya que quieres refrescar la pagina, he usado un JSFiddle porque el snippet de SOes no permite LocalStorage.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/lois6b/3wxvkvpc/

Es practicamente lo que tienes pero refrescando la pagina y guardando el ultimo idioma seleccionado en `LocalStorage`

```js
var lista = document.getElementById("idioma");
var idioma = localStorage.getItem("idioma");

var aa = {
  en: "Hello",
  es: "Hola"
};

if (idioma) {

  lista.value = idioma;
  document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = aa[idioma];
} else {

  document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = aa[lista.value];
}

var _lang = $("#idioma").val();

$("select").on("change", function() {
  cambiaId();
  location.reload();
});

function cambiaId() {
  _lang = $("#idioma").val();
  alert(_lang);
  localStorage.setItem("idioma", _lang)

}
```

```html
<select id="idioma">
      <option value="es">Español</option>
      <option value="en">Ingles</option>
    </select>

<div id="a">
</div>
```

---

Sin embargo, como dice Mariano en los comentarios de tu pregunta, por que no metes la asignacion de valor dentro de tu `cambiaId()`? Asi cargas igual los elementos pero no tienes que refrescar la pagina.

```js
var _lang = $("#idioma").val();

var aa = {
  en: "Hello",
  es: "Hola"
};

function cambiaId() {
  _lang = $("#idioma").val();
  alert(_lang)
  document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = aa[_lang];
}
document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = aa[_lang];
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="idioma" onchange="cambiaId()">
      <option value="es">Español</option>
      <option value="en">Ingles</option>
    </select>

<div id="a">
</div>
```

Comment: El único problema que veo es que has puesto `document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = aa[idioma];` dentro del script. Esto me lleva a un problema, si necesito traducir muchas variables el script se hara excesivamente grande.

Comment: Pero acabo de cambiarlo y con tu codigo y poniendo esa parte como yo la tenia antes funciona correctamente

Comment: Me alegro. Mirate [este enlace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084675/how-does-internationalization-work-in-javascript) ( en ingles :/ ) para aprender mas de la internacionalizacion en JS ^^

Comment: @AndoniAlda edité la respuesta para añadir lo que sugiere Mariano

Comment: Puedes comprobar la edicion?